# Avg Over time in Cube

Tags: ssas, measure

In fact table, I have column named `BusinessDays`.

> In Cube structure , I choose "Avg over time (Business Days) "in usage when I create new measure named Measure  A

I also have  time dimension in cube.

> In Calculations, I created measure B : Avg = SUM (Business Days)/Count (Business Days).

When I write the following `MDX`

- Using Measure A

  `select A on 0,
  [date].[Year].[2015] on 1
  From Cube`
- Using Measure B

  `select A on 0,
  [date].[Year].[2015] on 1
  From Cube`

But results are different from each other, Supposedly, results should be same. 
Actually , Measure B is correct.
Any Idea ?